# ERROR TypeError: Class constructor EventEmitter_ cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, angular-storybook

After upgrading to Angular 10, I am getting following error for some components -

```
ERROR TypeError: Class constructor EventEmitter_ cannot be invoked without 'new'
    at new ZoneAwareEventEmitter (index.js:34)
    at new GridComponent (index.js:6167)
    at createClass (core.js:21921)
    at createDirectiveInstance (core.js:21790)
    at createViewNodes (core.js:30281)
    at callViewAction (core.js:30597)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:30516)
    at createViewNodes (core.js:30309)
    at callViewAction (core.js:30597)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:30516)
```

The code that is causing this issue -

```
import { EventEmitter } from "@angular/core";

export class ZoneAwareEventEmitter extends EventEmitter {
    constructor(ngZone, isAsync = false) {
        super(isAsync);
        this.ngZone = ngZone;
    }
}
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Please post your component code as well.Make sure you are importing `EventEmitter` from `@angular/core`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I have updated the code

Comment: Also getting same problem, I am implementing storybook

Answer (score 2):

**Add this to Webpack config:**

```
resolve: {
    mainFields: ['es2015', 'browser', 'module', 'main']
},
```

---

The problem occurs in Webpack builds in projects using [Kendo Angular Grid](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/). The default Webpack configuration resolves the `fesm5` module from `node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-grid`, which tries to extend the EventEmitter class using es5 and results in the error. Changing the `mainFields` property of `resolve` inside Webpack config to prioritize `es2015` modules fixed this for me.

Comment: this is similar to the hint on this issue https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/11433#issue-651506779 and that is what worked for me to get kendo ui working in an NX angular workspace library